# The auto inject of Principle will be null if I manually set authentication

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to customize a login process in my own login controller instead of using UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

```java
 @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
          // authentication code here
         Authentication authenticate=this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
        return handlerAuthLogin(httpRequest, result, authorizationRequest);
    }
```

But I can't auto inject Principal in other controllers if I login success as below:

```java
@Controller
public class UsersController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/me")
  public string getMyName(Principal principal){
    return principal.getName(); // principal is null
  }
}
```

Any guys know why to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute `context.setAuthentication(authentication)` the authentication is only valid for the current request. So for the second `/me` request you need to set the authentication as well.
Therefore you need to authenticate the user on a per-request base. That can be done by implementing a `GenericFilterBean`:

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        /* 
           Note that you need to receive the authentication token in different manner now. 
           Usually headers are used for that.
        */
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(request.getHeader("authToken"));
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

After implementing the filter you need to register it in the servlet container at the position where it is best suited. Spring Security handles the security filters per `WebsecutiryConfigurer`, so you need to register your filter in the config of the respective configurer of your users.

As an example I put it after `ConcurrentSessionFilter`:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class UserWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter filter = new PlayerAuthenticationFilter(jwtService,
                objectMapper);

        http.addFilterAfter(filter, ConcurrentSessionFilter.class);

        (...)
    }

}
```

Check out the documentation about [filter ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html5/#filter-ordering) to find the position best suited for your method.

## Update

I wrote a more in-depth [blog post](https://www.code-held.com/2019/05/09/custom-authentication-with-spring-security/) about this topic. Fell free to check it out.

Answer (score -2):

@Marcus

Thanks for your clarification,  I found the cause for my case.

I wrongly config a

```java
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 public WebSecurityConfig() {
     super(true); // I disable the default config, so the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter didn't be added by default and all my SecurityContext info is not persistent
 }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it. Please keep in mind that on Stackoverflow answers should not be used for a conversation. That's whats comments like this one are for. And don't forget to accept an answer that solved your problem as well as upvoting helpful ones. That will reward the people that helped you and gives an easier orientation for everyone else visiting this question.